# How to add GitHub readme.md page to Google search console?

Tags: github, google-search

I would like to add GitHub `readme.md` page to Google search. But Google console need to check ownership of the domain. The problem is I am not the owner of GitHub domain and all suggested solutions seems to be useless. I can not add HTML page to the root nor add HTML meta tag nor Google tag JavaScript. I really don't know how to do it. Is there anybody who knows how to do it for GitHub?

Answer (score 4):

This may not be possible.

Per here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080#html_verification&zippy=%2Chtml-file-upload

The Options for verification are:

1. add html page in the root of your url (this will not work for github readmes as files in root are are in you main/master branch when you browse to them)
2. Embed a meta tag, [not allowed per github whitelist](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-pipeline/blob/main/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb#L44)
3. Google analytics, requires a js file be included in your readme, not allowed in your github.com readme page
4. Google Tag Manager, requires script in head, or iframe in body (not possible)
5. Domain name provider, this is not possible for github.com

Note:
It does look like one can verify the github pages site that github hosts for your repo using methods 1, 2, 3, or 4

I submitted the suggestion to have github allow meta tags here:
https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/40093