Google verification of very simple Github repo
After following these steps for indexing a simple Github repo (just code, no html or css etc.) via  https://search.google.com/search-console I am stuck on the verification step.
You are meant to add a Google supplied HTML file to the root of your repo. So if your repo is hosted at https://github.com/auser/arepo you would add the google supplied file to https://github.com/auser/arepo/google123456789abcde.html. At least that is my understanding.
But if I try to add a file it winds up as something like https://github.com/auser/arepo/tree/main/google123456789abcde.html and the verifcation fails.
I feel like I'm missing something pretty simple. I know that there are options to create config.yaml files that would manage your directory structure in your repo but for one thing that seems a bit overkill and for another thing that recurses to the same problem because the yaml file itself would (I think) need to be in the root directory of the repo.

This isn't GitHub Pages ...

Hmmm a bit more searching suggests that this cannot actually be done. Folks have suggested that Github support adding verification tags to README.md pages but this has not been implemented.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68344272/how-to-add-github-readme-md-page-to-google-search-console
https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/40093
https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/69416
